# Using jQuery/JavaScript Code in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, web-applications, jsp

I have jQuery code in a JSP:

```
${'#userid').val('admin')
```

The app server is interpreting the jQuery code as JSP:

```
The function val must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified
```

How do I "escape" the JavaScript?

Answer (score 5):

There is absolutely no problem in using javascript in jsp pages.

Your example does not work because it is not valid jQuery - instead it starts like an EL expression. Your first bracket should not be curly:

```
$('#userid').val('admin')
```

Comment: @teddy - if the answer works for you, feel free to mark it as accepted (tick below the vote counter)